# Issues in Web API and MVC 4 controllers using StructureMap

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, structuremap

I have started a Web API project, and extended it to also be a normal MVC project. By this I mean I have some controllers deriving from `ApiController` and others from `Controller`.

Here's my DependencyResolver:

```
public class StructureMapDependencyResolver :IDependencyResolver
{
    public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public StructureMapDependencyResolver(IContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        if (serviceType.IsAbstract || serviceType.IsInterface)
            return _container.TryGetInstance(serviceType);

        return _container.GetInstance(serviceType);
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return _container.GetAllInstances<object>()
                         .Where(s => s.GetType() == serviceType);
    }

    private readonly IContainer _container;

    public void Dispose() { }
}
```

and here's my Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);

    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.For<IDataService>().Use<MockDataService>();
        });
    ObjectFactory.Configure(x => x.Scan(scan =>
        {
            scan.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory();
            scan.LookForRegistries();
            scan.TheCallingAssembly();
            scan.WithDefaultConventions();
        }));

    var container = ObjectFactory.Container;
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = 
               new StructureMapDependencyResolver(container);
}
```

The Web API controllers are working great, but I can't get constructor injection to work in the `Controller`-derived ones. It's the usual `No parameterless constructor defined for this object` error message of course.

I'm at a bit of a loss here... this is my first foray into Web API so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the [DependencyResolver.SetResolver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg401985%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) to your MVC IOC container. Make sure your container implements MVC's IDependencyResolver as well, otherwise it won't work for MVC.